# Haskell. update a single Vector element in O(1)

Tags: haskell, vector

I want to write a function that updates a single vector element in O(1):

```
Vector Integer -> Int -> Integer -> Vector Integer
upd v ind x
```

It's easy to update a value copying the whole vector:

```
upd v ind x = v // [(ind,x)]
```

But that's way too slow.

I create a vector as `Data.Vector.Generic.fromList` and do not freeze it.

To modify the vector in-place I found function
`Data.Vector.modify`, `Data.Vector.Mutable.write` and `Data.Vector.Mutable.unsafeWrite`, but I can't figure out how to use any of them.

When I try this:

```
upd v ind x = do DVM.write v ind x
```

The compiler complains:

```
Couldn't match type `()' with `Integer'
Expected type: DV.Vector Integer
  Actual type: DV.Vector ()
In the return type of a call of `DVM.write'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: DVM.write v ind x
In the expression: do { DVM.write v ind x }
```

(DV = `Data.Vector`, DVM = `Data.Vector.Mutable`),

Any help is appreciated.
I'd be extra happy to get an example of using `Data.Vector.modify`.

Comment: This is _impossible_ with a normal vector; you must use a mutable vector to do this.

Comment: Do you mean that my function needs to be of type Data.Vector.Mutable.MVector -> Int -> Integer Data.Vector.Mutable.MVector ?

Comment: Er, not quite.  The function you need is exactly the write function, the type you want is exactly its type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First note that a `do` block with a single expression is always the same as that expression on its own. So you could just as well have written

```
upd v ind x = DVM.write v ind x
```

but this doesn't make sense for a couple of reasons.

1. `v` is still an immutable vector. Mutable vectors are something quite different, they are implemented with references to the state of a `PrimMonad` – nothing the like is normally needed for pure Haskell computations, because referential transparency guarantees that the state is always the same. Of course, that's precisely what prevents you from doing updates in *O* (1), and there's no real way to circumvent that. You need to enter one of those monads to get such updates.
2. because mutable vectors are “hidden” in the monad's state, you can't simply return them as a function result on their own. That would leak state to the pure-functional language, thus violating referential transparency. You have two options:

   - freeze the mutable vector to an immutable one, return that as result. Of course this can again only be done safely with a copy of the whole thing<sup>1</sup>, so it doesn't gain you anything over the much simpler `//` solution.
   - stay in the monad as long as you need to do updates. You never freeze the vector as long, it just keeps “floating” in the mutable state. That means you can't have a function signature like `upd`, but need to use only a monadic action. As Louis Wasserman said, this is *exactly* what `write` already does, so really you don't need to do anything more. (Which makes sense: if a function like the `upd` you envisioned was possible, it would certainly be already in the `vector` library.)

Now, that doesn't quite explain how to use mutable vectors, but to do that we'd need to know the context in which you had hoped to use `upd`. However, before you go mutable at all: why are you so sure that a simple pure update is to slow for your purpose? The `vector` library is pretty good at “batching” such updates by stream fusion; if you're doing *O* (*n*) independent updates then each can on avarage be *O* (1), because only one copy is made for all the updates.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>And the *thawing* when you inject the vector into the monad to become mutable may already require a copy, too.</sub>

Comment: I believe that in the worst case scenario, both freezing *and* thawing require copies. For example, `do {v<-freeze mv; write mv 1 'a'; v' <- freeze mv; return (v,v')}` requires the vector to be copied at least once because two different versions are frozen.

Comment: Thank you, I'll change the code to stay within a single ST monad.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is just:

```
> :t modify (\mv ->  write mv 10 'a')
modify (\mv ->  write mv 10 'a') :: Vector Char -> Vector Char

>  modify (\mv ->  write mv 10 'a') (fromList "Hello good comrades")
fromList "Hello goodacomrades"

>   modify (\mv ->  unsafeWrite mv 0 100) (fromList [1..20::Integer])
fromList [100,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

And continuing with the other operations you mention:

```
> :t  thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a'
thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a'
  :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m => m ()  -- i.e. IO or ST s

> :t  thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a' >> freeze mv
thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a' >> freeze mv
  :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m => m (Vector Char) 

> :t  thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a' >> freeze mv >>= print
thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a' >> freeze mv >>= print
  :: IO ()

> thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a' >> freeze mv >>= print
fromList "Hello goodacomrades"
```

Now importing `Control.Monad.ST` for `runST`

```
> :t runST
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a

> :t  thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a'
thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a'
 :: Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m => m ()  -- we will use ST s

> :t runST $ thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a' >> freeze mv
runST $ thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a' >> freeze mv
  :: Vector Char

> runST $ thaw (fromList "Hello good comrades") >>= \mv -> write mv 10 'a' >> freeze mv
fromList "Hello goodacomrades"
```

This is why the argument you give to `runST` is like the argument you give to `modify`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I now why thaw is important.